# 404 error: Access PHP Application in subfolder of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have wordpress installed in the root folder for my domain. This is my main website. 
Now i want to install a CodeIgnitor PHP application in a subfolder (it has nothing to do with wordpress, it just has to be in the same domain) so domain.com/folder/

I however get a 404 error in wordpress.

If I type domain/folder/index.php/login -> it takes me to the login page atleast - but i still cant go beyond.

Please help.

THis is my current .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried either proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

Those `rewritecond`s in WordPress' section of your `.htaccess` will ensure that any URL that isn't an actual file or directory will be handled by WP, so your CI never gets a chance to see it. Changing the rewrite rule as follows will exclude your subdir from WP's override.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!folder(?:$|/)). /index.php [L]
```

That's a negative look-ahead assertion which ensures That CI will get the URL if the path is only `/folder`, or is or begins with `/folder/`. You need both cases so Apache can do its normal handling of directory URLs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @walf. I tried this solution but now its throwing the server's 404 instead of Wordpress. I might be doing something wrong. This is my new .htaccess 'code

Comment: Added your rule at the end # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!office(?:$|/)). /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: 'code' # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!office(?:$|/)). /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress 'code'

Comment: So it's not working for you? A server 404 is a good sign if your URL begins with `yourdomain.com/office/` because WP is not generating the 404, which is what we're trying to achieve. If you temporarily rename the `.htaccess` file to disable all 'pretty' URLs, do you still get a 404 at the same URL?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

1. Login wp-admin
2. Go Settings → Permalinks
3. Update to **post name**

Comment: That won't stop WordPress stealing URLs, and then issuing 404s when no post/category/etc. matches.

Comment: i run same method to wordpress and CodeIgnitor.

Comment: And what happens when your URL begins with your CI subfolder, but doesn't correspond to a WP page or a CI one? Does the 404 come from CI as one would expect?

Comment: And don't downvote without a valid reason. This site is about finding the best solution and yours is certainly not.